# Sort comments by likes and dislikes

Tags: mysql

Help, please, correct the query, I need to sort comments by likes and dislikes (that is, by the sum of likes and dislays: cnt_total = cnt_like + cnt_dislike, who has more cnt_total is displayed above), and if cnt_total is equal - sort by date. cnt_total is just an example, it's not in the table.

Table comments with columns: id_comment, id_user, id_news, comment, id_parent, date_time, cnt_like, cnt_dislike, is_active.

```
SELECT u.login, c.* 
FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = c.id_user
WHERE id_news = '{$id_news}' AND c.is_active = 1 
ORDER BY id_parent, date_time DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.login, c.*, c.cnt_like + c.cnt_dislike AS cnt_total 
FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = c.id_user
WHERE id_news = '{$id_news}' AND c.is_active = 1 
ORDER BY cnt_total DESC, date_time DESC
```

Comment: c.cnt_like - c.cnt_like (c.cnt_like is positive number UNSIGNED and c.cnt_dislike is positive number UNSIGNED)

Comment: Uncaught Exception: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`c`.`cnt_like` - `c`.`cnt_dislike`)

Comment: Not sure I understand your comments? Is it working OK? I put cnt_like+cnt_dislike because that's what's in your question, but obviously easy enough to change to -.

Comment: I remove value UNSIGNED in columns cnt_like and cnt_dislike, because with UNSIGNED not work. And than - Yes, it's work OK!!!

Comment: Good to hear. If you wanted to leave the columns as UNSIGNED, you could use `CAST(c.cnt_like AS SIGNED)-CAST(c.cnt_dislike AS SIGNED) AS cnt_total`